# While creating an IBOutlet for a view in swift, the base class is appended with an?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

In swift, if I create an IBOutlet for a view this is what i get

```
  @IBOutlet weak var viewOne: UIView!
```

UIView? means that it is an optional, could be nil or not. But what does ! for the base class here mean? What i understand is ! is used to unwrap an optional value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defines `viewOne` as an implicitly unwrapped optional.

It's as if it were defined as `UIView?` and you called `viewOne!` everywhere. If `viewOne` is `nil` when you reference it, your app will crash.

As long as you're careful, this will save you the trouble of manually unwrapping the optional everywhere you use it.

I suggest you reread the section "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals" in the [The Basics section of the Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html). You may wish to reread the entire section.